Using spack compile c++ and get: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()@GLIBCXX_3.4.29'
I get the error while compiling C++ on the server using the spack virtual environment and get error

/usr/bin/ld: /home/panasun/spack/var/spack/environments/hydro/.spack-env/view/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()@GLIBCXX_3.4.29'

My spec is
Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   benchmark

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  benchmark@1.8.3%gcc@11.2.0~ipo+performance_counters build_system=cmake build_type=RelWithDebInfo generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^cmake@3.27.9%gcc@11.2.0~doc+ncurses+ownlibs build_system=generic build_type=Release arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^curl@8.7.1%gcc@11.2.0~gssapi~ldap~libidn2~librtmp~libssh~libssh2+nghttp2 build_system=autotools libs=shared,static tls=openssl arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^nghttp2@1.57.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^diffutils@3.10%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^openssl@3.3.0%gcc@11.2.0~docs+shared build_system=generic certs=mozilla arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^ca-certificates-mozilla@2023-05-30%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^perl@5.38.0%gcc@11.2.0+cpanm+opcode+open+shared+threads build_system=generic patches=714e4d1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^berkeley-db@18.1.40%gcc@11.2.0+cxx~docs+stl build_system=autotools patches=26090f4,b231fcc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^bzip2@1.0.8%gcc@11.2.0~debug~pic+shared build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^gdbm@1.23%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                      ^readline@8.2%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=bbf97f1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^pkgconf@2.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^ncurses@6.5%gcc@11.2.0~symlinks+termlib abi=none build_system=autotools patches=7a351bc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^zlib-ng@2.1.6%gcc@11.2.0+compat+new_strategies+opt+pic+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gmake@4.4.1%gcc@11.2.0~guile build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^libpfm4@4.13.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=makefile arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   libtomlc99

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  libtomlc99@0.2020.12.23%gcc@11.2.0~debug build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   cmake

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  mpileaks@1.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools stackstart=0 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^adept-utils@1.0.1%gcc@11.2.0~ipo build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^boost@1.72.0%gcc@11.2.0+atomic+chrono~clanglibcpp~container~context~contract~coroutine+date_time~debug~exception~fiber+filesystem~graph~graph_parallel~icu~iostreams~json~locale~log~math~mpi+multithreaded~nowide~numpy~pic~program_options~python~random~regex~serialization+shared~signals~singlethreaded~stacktrace+system~taggedlayout~test+thread+timer~type_erasure~versionedlayout~wave build_system=generic cxxstd=11 patches=5da7ad2,e13cca1 visibility=hidden arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^cmake@3.27.9%gcc@11.2.0~doc+ncurses+ownlibs build_system=generic build_type=Release arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^curl@8.7.1%gcc@11.2.0~gssapi~ldap~libidn2~librtmp~libssh~libssh2+nghttp2 build_system=autotools libs=shared,static tls=openssl arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^nghttp2@1.57.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^ncurses@6.5%gcc@11.2.0~symlinks+termlib abi=none build_system=autotools patches=7a351bc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^callpath@1.0.4%gcc@11.2.0~ipo build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^dyninst@13.0.0%gcc@11.2.0~ipo+openmp~stat_dysect~static build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^intel-tbb@2021.9.0%gcc@11.2.0~ipo+shared+tm build_system=cmake build_type=Release cxxstd=default generator=make patches=91755c6 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libiberty@2.41%gcc@11.2.0+pic build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^elfutils@0.190%gcc@11.2.0~debuginfod+exeprefix+nls build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^bzip2@1.0.8%gcc@11.2.0~debug~pic+shared build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^diffutils@3.10%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^gettext@0.22.5%gcc@11.2.0+bzip2+curses+git~libunistring+libxml2+pic+shared+tar+xz build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^tar@1.34%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools zip=pigz arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                      ^pigz@2.8%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=makefile arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^m4@1.4.19%gcc@11.2.0+sigsegv build_system=autotools patches=9dc5fbd,bfdffa7 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^libsigsegv@2.14%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^xz@5.4.6%gcc@11.2.0~pic build_system=autotools libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^zstd@1.5.6%gcc@11.2.0+programs build_system=makefile compression=none libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^libdwarf@20180129%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gmake@4.4.1%gcc@11.2.0~guile build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^openmpi@5.0.3%gcc@11.2.0~atomics~cuda~gpfs~internal-hwloc~internal-libevent~internal-pmix~java~legacylaunchers~lustre~memchecker~openshmem~orterunprefix~romio+rsh~static+vt+wrapper-rpath build_system=autotools fabrics=none romio-filesystem=none schedulers=none arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^autoconf@2.72%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^automake@1.16.5%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^hwloc@2.9.1%gcc@11.2.0~cairo~cuda~gl~libudev+libxml2~netloc~nvml~oneapi-level-zero~opencl+pci~rocm build_system=autotools libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libpciaccess@0.17%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^util-macros@1.19.3%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libxml2@2.10.3%gcc@11.2.0+pic~python+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^libevent@2.1.12%gcc@11.2.0+openssl build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^openssl@3.3.0%gcc@11.2.0~docs+shared build_system=generic certs=mozilla arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^ca-certificates-mozilla@2023-05-30%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^libtool@2.4.7%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^findutils@4.9.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=440b954 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^numactl@2.0.14%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=4e1d78c,62fc8a8,ff37630 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^openssh@9.7p1%gcc@11.2.0+gssapi build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^krb5@1.20.1%gcc@11.2.0+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^bison@3.8.2%gcc@11.2.0~color build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libedit@3.1-20230828%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libxcrypt@4.4.35%gcc@11.2.0~obsolete_api build_system=autotools patches=4885da3 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^perl@5.38.0%gcc@11.2.0+cpanm+opcode+open+shared+threads build_system=generic patches=714e4d1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^berkeley-db@18.1.40%gcc@11.2.0+cxx~docs+stl build_system=autotools patches=26090f4,b231fcc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^gdbm@1.23%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^readline@8.2%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=bbf97f1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^pkgconf@2.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^pmix@5.0.1%gcc@11.2.0~docs+pmi_backwards_compatibility~python~restful build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^zlib-ng@2.1.6%gcc@11.2.0+compat+new_strategies+opt+pic+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   mpileaks

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  gmake@4.4.1%gcc@11.2.0~guile build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   gdal

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  gdal@3.8.5%gcc@11.2.0~archive~armadillo~arrow~basisu~blosc~brunsli~cfitsio~crnlib~cryptopp~csharp+curl~deflate~ecw+expat~filegdb~freexl~fyba+geos~gif~gta~hdf4~hdf5~hdfs~heif~iconv~idb~ipo~java+jpeg~jxl~kdu~kea~lerc~libaec~libcsf~libkml~liblzma~libqb3~libxml2~luratech~lz4~mongocxx~mrsid~mssql_ncli~mssql_odbc~mysql~netcdf~odbc~odbccpp~ogdi~opencad~opencl~openexr~openjpeg~openssl~oracle~parquet~pcidsk~pcre2~pdfium+png~podofo~poppler~postgresql~python~qhull~rasterlite2~rdb~sfcgal~spatialite+sqlite3~teigha~tiledb~webp~xercesc~zstd build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=ninja patches=52459dc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^cmake@3.27.9%gcc@11.2.0~doc+ncurses+ownlibs build_system=generic build_type=Release arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^gmake@4.4.1%gcc@11.2.0~guile build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^ncurses@6.5%gcc@11.2.0~symlinks+termlib abi=none build_system=autotools patches=7a351bc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^curl@8.7.1%gcc@11.2.0~gssapi~ldap~libidn2~librtmp~libssh~libssh2+nghttp2 build_system=autotools libs=shared,static tls=openssl arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^nghttp2@1.57.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^diffutils@3.10%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^openssl@3.3.0%gcc@11.2.0~docs+shared build_system=generic certs=mozilla arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^ca-certificates-mozilla@2023-05-30%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^perl@5.38.0%gcc@11.2.0+cpanm+opcode+open+shared+threads build_system=generic patches=714e4d1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^berkeley-db@18.1.40%gcc@11.2.0+cxx~docs+stl build_system=autotools patches=26090f4,b231fcc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^bzip2@1.0.8%gcc@11.2.0~debug~pic+shared build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^gdbm@1.23%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^expat@2.6.2%gcc@11.2.0+libbsd build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^libbsd@0.12.1%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libmd@1.0.4%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^geos@3.12.1%gcc@11.2.0~ipo+shared build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=ninja arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^json-c@0.16%gcc@11.2.0~ipo build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^libgeotiff@1.7.1%gcc@11.2.0+jpeg+proj+zlib build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^libjpeg-turbo@3.0.0%gcc@11.2.0~ipo~jpeg8~partial_decoder+pic build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^nasm@2.15.05%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^libpng@1.6.39%gcc@11.2.0~ipo~pic build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^libtiff@4.5.1%gcc@11.2.0+ccitt~ipo~jbig+jpeg~jpeg12~lerc~libdeflate+logluv~lzma+lzw+next~old-jpeg+packbits~pic~pixarlog+shared+thunder~webp+zlib~zstd build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^ninja@1.11.1%gcc@11.2.0+re2c build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^python@3.11.7%gcc@11.2.0+bz2+crypt+ctypes+dbm~debug+libxml2+lzma~nis~optimizations+pic+pyexpat+pythoncmd+readline+shared+sqlite3+ssl~tkinter+uuid+zlib build_system=generic patches=13fa8bf,b0615b2,ebdca64,f2fd060 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^gettext@0.22.5%gcc@11.2.0+bzip2+curses+git~libunistring+libxml2+pic+shared+tar+xz build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^libxml2@2.10.3%gcc@11.2.0+pic~python+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^tar@1.34%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools zip=pigz arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                      ^pigz@2.8%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=makefile arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                      ^zstd@1.5.6%gcc@11.2.0+programs build_system=makefile compression=none libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libffi@3.4.6%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libxcrypt@4.4.35%gcc@11.2.0~obsolete_api build_system=autotools patches=4885da3 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^util-linux-uuid@2.38.1%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^xz@5.4.6%gcc@11.2.0~pic build_system=autotools libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^re2c@2.2%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^pkgconf@2.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^proj@9.2.1%gcc@11.2.0+curl~ipo~pic+shared+tiff build_system=cmake build_type=Release generator=make arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^sqlite@3.43.2%gcc@11.2.0+column_metadata+dynamic_extensions+fts~functions+rtree build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^readline@8.2%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=bbf97f1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^zlib-ng@2.1.6%gcc@11.2.0+compat+new_strategies+opt+pic+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   gmake

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  cmake@3.27.9%gcc@11.2.0~doc+ncurses+ownlibs build_system=generic build_type=Release arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^curl@8.7.1%gcc@11.2.0~gssapi~ldap~libidn2~librtmp~libssh~libssh2+nghttp2 build_system=autotools libs=shared,static tls=openssl arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^nghttp2@1.57.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^diffutils@3.10%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^openssl@3.3.0%gcc@11.2.0~docs+shared build_system=generic certs=mozilla arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^ca-certificates-mozilla@2023-05-30%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^perl@5.38.0%gcc@11.2.0+cpanm+opcode+open+shared+threads build_system=generic patches=714e4d1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^berkeley-db@18.1.40%gcc@11.2.0+cxx~docs+stl build_system=autotools patches=26090f4,b231fcc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^bzip2@1.0.8%gcc@11.2.0~debug~pic+shared build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^gdbm@1.23%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^readline@8.2%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=bbf97f1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^pkgconf@2.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gmake@4.4.1%gcc@11.2.0~guile build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^ncurses@6.5%gcc@11.2.0~symlinks+termlib abi=none build_system=autotools patches=7a351bc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^zlib-ng@2.1.6%gcc@11.2.0+compat+new_strategies+opt+pic+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Input spec
--------------------------------
 -   gcc

Concretized
--------------------------------
[+]  gcc@13.2.0%gcc@11.2.0~binutils+bootstrap~graphite~nvptx~piclibs~profiled~strip build_system=autotools build_type=RelWithDebInfo languages='c,c++,fortran' arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^diffutils@3.10%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gawk@5.3.0%gcc@11.2.0~nls build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^libsigsegv@2.14%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^readline@8.2%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=bbf97f1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gcc-runtime@11.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[e]      ^glibc@2.31%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gmake@4.4.1%gcc@11.2.0~guile build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^gmp@6.2.1%gcc@11.2.0+cxx build_system=autotools libs=shared,static patches=69ad2e2 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^autoconf@2.72%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^automake@1.16.5%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^m4@1.4.19%gcc@11.2.0+sigsegv build_system=autotools patches=9dc5fbd,bfdffa7 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^libtool@2.4.7%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^findutils@4.9.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools patches=440b954 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^mpc@1.3.1%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^mpfr@4.2.1%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^autoconf-archive@2023.02.20%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^perl@5.38.0%gcc@11.2.0+cpanm+opcode+open+shared+threads build_system=generic patches=714e4d1 arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^berkeley-db@18.1.40%gcc@11.2.0+cxx~docs+stl build_system=autotools patches=26090f4,b231fcc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^bzip2@1.0.8%gcc@11.2.0~debug~pic+shared build_system=generic arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^gdbm@1.23%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^texinfo@7.0.3%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^gettext@0.22.5%gcc@11.2.0+bzip2+curses+git~libunistring+libxml2+pic+shared+tar+xz build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^libxml2@2.10.3%gcc@11.2.0+pic~python+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^tar@1.34%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools zip=pigz arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]                  ^pigz@2.8%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=makefile arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^xz@5.4.6%gcc@11.2.0~pic build_system=autotools libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]          ^ncurses@6.5%gcc@11.2.0~symlinks+termlib abi=none build_system=autotools patches=7a351bc arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]              ^pkgconf@2.2.0%gcc@11.2.0 build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^zlib-ng@2.1.6%gcc@11.2.0+compat+new_strategies+opt+pic+shared build_system=autotools arch=linux-debian11-zen3
[+]      ^zstd@1.5.6%gcc@11.2.0+programs build_system=makefile compression=none libs=shared,static arch=linux-debian11-zen3

Do you have any suggestions or any dependencies I have to add?
If you want more detail, please let me know.

Most likely libgdal.so was compiled against a newer version of libc than is available on your system

@AlanBirtles Thank you very much for the comment. So it means that I have to use the older version of libc right? I am a Ph.D. in computational science (mainly mathematics). I don't have much knowledge about the computer. So could you please answer it more clearly.

I'm afraid i have even less knowledge about your computer than you do

Ok! Thank you again for your guide.

This is odd, maybe you want to skip the gcc spec, just use your computer gcc as an external package.

Thanks. I also try with native gcc but it does not work.

Where does your GDAL come from? Why don't you use the distribution-provided one?
